# Google Apps change primary e-mail address in bulk

Tags: google-apps-script

Our company will soon change its domain and we also want to change our main e-mail addresses at the same time. The Google Apps admin panel does have an option to [change the primary e-mail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182084?hl=en) of a given account, which will create an alias that forwards e-mail from the old to the new primary domain. However, that method has to be repeated for each of the users in the organisation.

I think Google Apps Script can be used to accomplish that behaviour for all users at once but I don't exactly know how.

If anyone could provide a sample code or guide me on the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using the Directory API: User Accounts

> Renaming a user account changes the user's primary email address and
>   the domain used when retrieving this user's information.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

Comment: So I would have to create a Google Apps Script that iterates through all users and and uses the Directory API to update the primary address, wouldn't I?